# How to integrate the reorder function into the dplyr pipeline?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on some exercises that ask to integrate `reorder` as part of a dplyr pipeline. I haven't found out how, however. I simply have to use an alternative solution with `arrange` e.g.

```
# The `errors` data have already been loaded. Examine them using the `head` function.
head(errors)

# Create a boxplot showing the errors by state for polls with grades B+ or higher
errors %>% filter(grade %in% c("A+", "A", "A-", "B+")) %>% 
    arrange(error) %>% ggplot(aes(x=state,y=error)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_point()
```

I use the `arrange` function in this fashion and it passes the grader, thus arranging all results ASC by error but I can't find out how to integrate the `reorder` function in this pipeline and to accomplish the use-case of sorting by error.

Besides, ggplot doesn't seem to be picking on the correct reordering of the data.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: `reorder` modifies a column (vector). The `dplyr` function that wraps column changes is `mutate`. So `... %>% mutate(new_column = reorder(old_column, reference_column)) %>% ... `

Comment: btw, `arrange` changes the order of rows. In almost all cases, `ggplot` doesn't care about the order of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working because your solution is the logical one, but not the right one.

`ggplot2` isn't changing the resultant plot because it doesn't care about the order of the lines in a data.frame/tibble.

To reorder the data points in your plot you have to change the order of the factors in you dataset. You can do it using `library(forcats)`. The following code snippet might help you.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

errors %>% 
   dplyr::filter(grade %in% c("A+", "A", "A-", "B+")) %>%  
   dplyr::mutate(error = forcats::fct_reorder(error, grades)) %>% #here I'm reordering the factors of the error column based in the grade column.
   ggplot(aes(x=state,y=error)) + 
   geom_boxplot() + 
   geom_point()
```